# Autowire Generic repository in JPA

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

How can we Autowire the Generic repository in JPA:
Ex:

```
Generic reposiroty:
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface CustomTestRepository<T,ID extends Serializable> extends JpaRepository<T, ID> {

}

Service Class:
@Service
public class StudentService {
    @Autowired
    CustomTestRepository<Student,Integer> customRepo;

    public void saveStudent(Student student){
      customRepo.save(student)
    }
}
Entity:
@Entity
class Student{
...
}
```

I saw many link which they are implementing the FactoryBean and overriding the save functionality. But they end up no where(Fail to implement). Please suggest with an example or references.

Comment: What is the issue you are facing with mentioned code ?

Comment: You cannot autowire the repository with annotation `@NoRepositoryBean`

Answer (score 1):

The @NoRepositoryBean annotation indicates spring not to instantiate a repository class that implements such interface. That part is correct but when you try to inject one directly there is no bean available for injection.

You first need to declare an interface that extends the generic with the desired entity type to instruct spring to create such a bean:

```
@Repository
public interface StudentRepository extends CustomTestRepository<Student, Integer> {

}
```

And then you are able to add it as a dependency on other beans:

```
@Service
public class StudentService {
    @Autowired
    StudentRepository studentRepository;

    public void saveStudent(Student student){
      studentRepository.save(student)
    }
}
```

Comment: Just to expand on your answer: once you do that, nothing's stopping you from still using `@Autowired CustomTestRepository<Student, Integer> studentRepository`

Comment: @crizzis very cool! didn't know that, but makes sense

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Problem is I will be having 100's of entities on which I need to just call save for all. I cannot create that many repositories. Just want to know if there is a generic way to creating custom repository so that I can just pass entity name and ID.